# Confluent schema registry SSL configuration

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, apache-kafka-security

I am new to the kafka field.

I have kafka, zookeeper and schema registry all installed in a RHEL7 machine (hostname: `kafka-confluent`), it is not a cluster setup so there is only 1 broker.

Now I would like to configure SSL encryption for my setup. I have created ssl keys and certificate according to the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/security/security_tutorial.html#generating-keys-certs).

Then I configured the properties files.

My (confluent platform install dir) `/etc/kafka/server.properties`:

```
ssl.truststore.location=/home/kafka/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.keystore.location=/home/kafka/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
ssl.client.auth=required
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSL://:9093
```

My (confluent platform install dir) `/etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties`:

```
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081,https://0.0.0.0:8082
ssl.truststore.location=/home/kafka/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.keystore.location=/home/kafka/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.client.auth=true
```

I already have a topic `test` created before, when I publish the message in the server, it failed:

```
[kafka@kafka-confluent ~]$ echo "Hello, World" | /home/kafka/confluent-5.4.0/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic test > /dev/null

[2020-02-20 18:45:12,193] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 13 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Then I checked the `server.log`, it shows failed authentication:

```
[2020-02-20 18:45:47,754] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with /127.0.0.1 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worth checking [`ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html#optional-settings):

> The endpoint identification algorithm used by clients to validate
>   server host name. The default value is `https`. Clients including client
>   connections created by the broker for inter-broker communication
>   verify that the broker host name matches the host name in the broker’s
>   certificate. Disable server host name verification by setting
>   `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm` to an empty string

Therefore, setting `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm` to an empty string should do the trick:

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

---

Note that this config prevents man-in-the-middle attacks therefore consider configuring it accordingly.

Comment: Hi, I have added `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=` to server.properties and restarted kafka, unfortunately, it is still showing the same error.